# jquery fadeIn leaves opacity at 0

Tags: jquery, fadein

I have this weird behavior with `.fadeIn()`

If I write

```
$('#MyDiv').show();
```

The div shows just fine.

However, if I write

```
$('#MyDiv').fadeIn(400);
```

The div shows but with opacity `0`!

The line before is:

```
$('#MyDiv').hide()
    .html(TheHTML)
    .css('top', 0);
```

**UPDATE:** if I write `$('#MyDiv').show(400);`

The div also stays at opacity `0`.

Comment: if an element has opacity:0 === is not visible. But you say: "**The div shows but with opacity 0!**" I really don't understand

Comment: Where does `TheHTML` come from ? The problem certainly comes from somewhere else, like maybe your div is empty so its height and width is equal to 0 or something like that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Some CSS is overriding your div when it is hidden..Better add the opacity style to your div as 1.**

Else do,

```
$('#MyDiv').css('opacity','1');
```

**After your fadeIn call...**

Comment: CSS opacity value is 0 to 1. 100? A little bit big.

Answer (score 6):

Try jQuery [.fadeTo](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) function.

```
.fadeTo( duration, opacity [, callback] )  
.fadeTo( duration, opacity [, easing] [, callback] )
```

**Sample:**

```
$('#book').fadeTo('slow', 0.5, function() {
  // Animation complete.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The following will make it visible as you want

```
$('#MyDiv').animate({
  opacity: 1
},400);
```

You can try following:

```
$('#MyDiv').fadeIn(400, function(){
    $(this).css('opacity', 1)
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/5r3TP/1/)**

But I think your should also work just fine. See **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/5r3TP/3/)**

Comment: Doesn't `fadeIn` animates opacity itself? So maybe the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a

```
opacity: 0 !important;

//or

opacity: 0;
```

In your css in that case you have to change `opacity` manually yourself like this

```
$('#MyDiv').fadeIn(400,function(){
   $(this).css('opacity',1);
});
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/PHD7k/1/). First div will never appear.